# Is there a way to install animate.css via Bower/Homebrew/etc?

Tags: wordpress, development-environment, animate.css

I've finally started developing locally and have installed Roots.io for WP builds.  Bower, gulp, node, it's all great.  I've used Bower to install wow.js and it's there, but the dependency is animate.css.  Is there a way to install animate.css via Bower/Homebrew/etc?

On the animate.css Github I don't see a simple way to include it in the Roots build.  I've tried to manually include in  which hasn't worked either, hence looking for the ideal/clean solution to the problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installing dependancies via bower (or any package manager really) that project should include a manifest (bower.json) that lists it's own dependancies. E.g. The bower.json in wow.js should include a reference to animate.css. However if it does not you can include it as any other dependancy:

```
bower install animate-css --save
```

Then run you build process again. In this case:

```
gulp
```